# Displaying doubles to a certain precision in java

Tags: java, numbers, double, precision

I am currently writing a calculator application. I know that a double is not the best choice for good math. Most of the functions in the application have great precision but the ones that don't get super ugly results. My solution is to show users only 12 decimals of precision. I chose 12 because my lowest precision comes from my numerical derive function.

The issue I am having is that if I multiply it by a scaler then round then divide by the scaler the precision will most likely be thrown out of whack. If I use DecimalFormat there is no way to show only 12 and have the E for scientific notation show up correctly, but not be there if it doesn’t need to be.

for example I want

```
1.23456789111213 to be 1.234567891112
```

but never

```
1.234567891112E0
```

but I also want

```
1.23456789111213E23 to be 1.234567891112E23
```

So basically I want to format the string of a number to 12 decimals places, preserving scientific notation, but not being scientific when it shouldn't

Comment: See what you're doing? Short-cutting can lead to hard work! You know double isn't the correct choice, but as you are used to it you are willing to try and overcome double's problems when you should, in fact, be learning how to use BigDecimal (as suggested!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.format("%.12G", doubleVariable);`

That is how you use format() to display values in scientific notation, but without the scientific notation if not needed.  The one caveat is that you end up with a '+' after the 'E', so yours would end up like 1.234567891112E+23

Comment: THANK YOU, i kind of actually like the +, I will add your name to the list of "thanks to" in the application, if you don't want to show up as Justin Waugh

Answer (score 0):

```
String.format("%.12d", doubleVariable);
```

Should give you what you are looking for in your first matter. I'm sorry but I don't know how to define when your E-notification is showed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be interested in BigDecimal, for example:

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("1.23456789111213");
number = number.setScale(12, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(number);
```

Choose appropriate to you RoundingMode.

Comment: How does this help with `1.23456789111213E23` ?

Comment: BigDecimal has toEngineeringString method which help you with this notation - but in this solution you should decide if you want display science notation or not