# How to get high precision answers when using double values in Java?

Tags: java

I am just trying to get an understanding of how to calculate various values when working in java. I started out by learning about the BigDecimal class and how I can use that to calculate with high precision. I understand the following concept:

```
    BigDecimal xx = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1);
    BigDecimal yy = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.2);


    System.out.printf("Number is: %s", xx.add(yy,new MathContext(30, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)).toString());
```

I get the result I expect of 0.3. What I tried next and am still stuck on is displaying really long decimal values after the calculation. I have 2 examples.

```
    BigDecimal xx = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.111111111111111111111111111111);
    BigDecimal yy = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.001111111111111111111111111111);


    System.out.printf("Number is: %s", xx.add(yy,new MathContext(30, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)).toString());
```

The result should be 0.112222...222, but comes out to 0.1122222222222222111.

The second example is using subtract instead of add. The answer should be 0.11, but instead I end up with 0.1099999999999999889.

I guess my question comes in two parts. Part one consists of how I am able to fix the above examples to get a correct answer and Part two is a little more general. I ultimately want to run some physic calculations that I would like to have very high precision on, say 20-30 decimal places. How can I perform my calculations so that I am preserving my answers and display them with small rounding issues and/or truncation?

Answer (score 5):

> BigDecimal xx = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.111111111111111111111111111111);

You are using `double` literals here, that have a limited precision and a prone to rounding errors.

Use decimals all the way.

> BigDecimal xx = new BigDecimal("0.111111111111111111111111111111");

Of course, if the long number is not something hard-coded into the program, but the result of a floating point calculation, then you already have the rounding error, and will have to live with it. Converting to BigDecimal cannot fix that anymore.

> How can I perform my calculations so that I am preserving my answers and display them with small rounding issues and/or truncation?

Except for rounding when printing, there is not much you can do.
[Printf has format strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558870/displaying-doubles-to-a-certain-precision-in-java?rq=1) for that like "%.12d".

Comment: My understanding is that the BigDecimal preserves the number so that it is handled with higher precision. If I were able to convert the decimals into string representations and feed into BigDecimal, would that help get out to the precision i need?

Comment: Where you do you get the decimals from? BigDecimal won't lose any decimals, but can you do your calculations in decimals? For example, dividing by three or calculating cosines will lead to floating point inprecision.

Answer (score 2):

> I guess my question comes in two parts. Part one consists of how I am able to fix the above examples to get a correct answer

Use the constructor which takes a String

```
BigDecimal xx = new BigDecimal("0.111111111111111111111111111111");
BigDecimal yy = new BigDecimal("0.001111111111111111111111111111");
```

> Part two is a little more general. I ultimately want to run some physic calculations that I would like to have very high precision on, say 20-30 decimal places.

You should be are that BigDecimal can be 100x slower and there is very little in the real world you can measure to 15 digits of accuracy.  I would rethink what "physic" problem really requires 20-30 digits of accuracy.

Comment: +1 for the last part. "Physic problems" should be fine with floating points, and things like trigonometry don't lend themselves to decimal calculations either.

Comment: The estimated US debt is $16.369 trillion, even written in cents this estimate is 16,369,000,000,000.00 which is sixteen digits of precision.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with that last example. Financial services applications should most definitely *not* use floating points.

Comment: @Thilo And yet most investment banks do, successfully. C and C++ don't have BigDecimal and yet they are used for trading systems.

Comment: Interesting. But do they use floats? Or fixed-precision numbers (such as scaled ints)?

Comment: @Thilo `double` but not `float`  Fixed precision is also used but less often than BigDecimal.  I have seen `double` used for quantities even when `int` would have been fine. i.e. perhaps over used if anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is the hard part of your Question:

> I ultimately want to run some physic calculations that I would like to have very high precision on, say 20-30 decimal places. How can I perform my calculations so that I am preserving my answers and display them with small rounding issues and/or truncation?

There is no simple answer to this.  It really depends on the nature of the "physics calculation".  Some calculations are relatively immune to error; i.e. the rounding errors don't much affect the final answer.  In other cases (e.g. with chaotic systems) the errors build up rapidly and eventually swamp the answer.

It can also matter *how* you do the calculations.  For instance there is one basic statistical calculation that involves calculation the difference between two "sums of squares" (or something like that).  The SoS values are typically very large, but the difference is small.  If you do the calculation the wrong way you get an imprecise value for the difference.  Another problem where *how* you do the calculation can matter is matrix inversion.

For what it is worth, there is a branch of mathematics that deals with numerical calculations and accuracy.  It is called Numerical Analysis.  In "the good old days", it was part of Computer Science courses.

Comment: I will look into Numerical Analysis as you seems to understand what I am trying to get at. The repetitive small errors growing large in a physics simulation. I am starting to see that there are specific tricks depending on the simulation and calculation, so I will stick to those for now. Thank you Stephen