# double operation wrong answer in Java

Tags: java

I have a double, say r = 1.44, r - 1.0 is supposed to be 0.44, but I got 0.439999995, I think there is an overflow, but I don't know where I did wrong. 
I tried to use r - 1.0, r - 1, or (double)(r - 1.0), nothing works.

Thanks.

Probably I should make it more clearly. I am trying to solve this problem on Cracking the code interview:

> Given a (decimal - e.g. 3.72) number that is passed in as a string,
>   print the binary representation. If the number can not be represented
>   accurately in binary, print “ERROR”

Here is my code based on the solution provided by the book:

```
public class DecimalToBinary {
    public static String binary (String decimal){
        if (decimal == null || decimal.length() == 0)
            return decimal;
        boolean hasPoint = false;
        int pointP = 0;
        if (decimal.contains(".")) {
            hasPoint = true;
            pointP = decimal.indexOf('.');
        }
        StringBuilder intString = new StringBuilder();
        int intPart = Integer.parseInt(hasPoint ? decimal.substring(0, pointP) : decimal);
        while (intPart > 0){
            intString.append(intPart % 2);
            intPart >>= 1;
        }
        if (!hasPoint)
            return intString.toString();
        StringBuilder decString = new StringBuilder();
        double decPart = Double.parseDouble(decimal.substring(pointP)); 
        if (decPart == 0)
            return intString.toString();
        while (decPart > 0){
            if (decPart == 1) {
                decString.append(1);
                break;
            }
            double r = decPart * 2.0;
            System.out.println("r " + r);
            if (r >= 1) {
                decString.append(1);
                decPart = (double)(r - 1);
                System.out.println("dec " +  decPart);
            }
            else {
                decString.append(0);
                decPart = r;
            }
        }
        return intString.toString() + "." + decString.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(binary("3.72"));
    }
}
```

Then I realize it's not giving me the correct answer, and I found out that it is because of the r. Since my goal is to print out the variable, so probably I would need some other approach?

Comment: No overflow, just the usual inaccuracy embedded in floating-point types and operations. If it's the printout that you're worried about, just print to a certain number of digits past the decimal point (two digits, according to your example).

Comment: Also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371132/how-to-get-high-precision-answers-when-using-double-values-in-java?rq=1 ... for hints on how to get more accuracy using `BigDecimal`.

Comment: And this `System.out.println(0.1 + 0.2);` from [SMBC 2999](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2999)